# Julia on Float versus Octave on Float

Tags: julia, numeric

**Version**: v"0.5.0-dev+1259"

**Context**: The goal is to calculate the Rademacher penalty bound on a give data points `n` with respect to VC-dimension `dvc` and probability expressed by `delta`

Please consider Julia code:

```
#Growth function on any n points with respect to VC-dimmension 
function mh(n, dvc) 
    if n <= dvc 
        2^n #A
    else 
        n^dvc #B
    end
end

#Rademacher penalty bound
function rademacher_penalty_bound(n::Int, dvc::Int, delta::Float64)
    sqrt((2.0*log(2.0*n*mh(n,dvc)))/n) + sqrt((2.0/n)*log(1.0/delta)) + 1.0/n   
end
```

and the equivalent code in Octave/Matlab:

```
%Growth function on n points for a give VC dimmension (dvc)
function md = mh(n, dvc)
  if n <= dvc
    md= 2^n;
  else
    md = n^dvc;
  end
end

%Rademacher penalty bound
function epsilon = rademacher_penalty_bound (n, dvc, delta)
  epsilon = sqrt ((2*log(2*n*mh(n,dvc)))/n) + sqrt((2/n)*log(1/delta)) + 1/n;
end
```

**Problem**:
When I start testing it I receive the following results:

Julia first:

```
julia> rademacher_penalty_bound(50, 50, 0.05) #50 points
1.619360057204432

julia> rademacher_penalty_bound(500, 50, 0.05) #500 points
ERROR: DomainError:
 [inlined code] from math.jl:137
 in rademacher_penalty_bound at none:2
 in eval at ./boot.jl:264
```

Now Octave:

```
octave:17> rademacher_penalty_bound(50, 50, 0.05)
ans =  1.6194
octave:18> rademacher_penalty_bound(500, 50, 0.05)
ans =  1.2387
```

**Question**: According to [Noteworthy differences from MATLAB](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/noteworthy-differences/) I think I followed the rule of thumb ("literal numbers without a decimal point (such as 42) create integers instead of floating point numbers..."). The code crashes when the number of points exceeds 51 (line #B in `mh`). Can someone with more experience can look at the code and say what I should improve/change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `BigInt` and `BigFloat` will work here, they're serious overkill. The real issue is that you're doing integer exponentiation in Julia and floating-point exponentiation in Octave/Matlab. So you just need to change `mh` to use floats instead of integers for exponents:

```
mh(n, dvc) = n <= dvc ? 2^float(n) : n^float(dvc)

rademacher_penalty_bound(n, dvc, δ) =
    √((2log(2n*mh(n,dvc)))/n) + √(2log(1/δ)/n) + 1/n
```

With these definitions, you get the same results as Octave/Matlab:

```
julia> rademacher_penalty_bound(50, 50, 0.05)
1.619360057204432

julia> rademacher_penalty_bound(500, 50, 0.05)
1.2386545010981596
```

In Octave/Matlab, even when you input a literal without a decimal point, you still get a float – you have to do an explicit cast to int type. Also, exponentiation in Octave/Matlab always converts to float first. In Julia, `x^2` is equivalent to `x*x` which prohibits conversion to floating-point.

Answer (score 3):

Although `BigInt` and `BigFloat` are excellent tools when they are necessary, they should usually be avoided, since they are overkill and slow.

In this case, the problem is indeed the difference between Octave, that treats everything as a floating-point number, and Julia, that treats e.g. 2 as an integer.

So the first thing to do is to use floating-point numbers in Julia too:

```
function mh(n, dvc) 
    if n <= dvc 
        2.0 ^ n 
    else 
        Float64(n) ^ dvc 
    end
end
```

This already helps, e.g. `mh(50, 50)` works.

*However*, the correct solution for this problem is to look at the code more carefully, and realise that the function `mh` only occurs inside a `log`:

```
log(2.0*n*mh(n,dvc))
```

We can use the laws of logarithms to rewrite this as

```
log(2.0*n) + log_mh(n, dvc)
```

where `log_mh` is a new function, which returns the logarithm of the result of `mh`. Of course, this should not be written directly as `log(mh(n, dvc))`, but is rather a new function:

```
function log_mh(n, dvc) 
    if n <= dvc 
        n * log(2.0)
    else 
        dvc * log(n) 
    end
end
```

In this way, you will be able to use huge numbers without overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know is it acceptable to get results of `BigFloat` but anyway in julia part you can use `BigInt`

```
#Growth function on any n points with respect to VC-dimmension 
function mh(n, dvc) 
    if n <= dvc 
        (BigInt(2))^n #A
    else 
        n^dvc #B
    end
end

#Rademacher penalty bound
function rademacher_penalty_bound(n::BigInt, dvc::BigInt, delta::Float64)
    sqrt((2.0*log(2.0*n*mh(n,dvc)))/n) + sqrt((2.0/n)*log(1.0/delta)) + 1.0/n   
end

rademacher_penalty_bound(BigInt(500), BigInt(500), 0.05)
# => 1.30055251010957621105182244420.....
```

Answer (score -1):

Because by default a Julia Int is a "machine-size" integer, a 64-bit integer for the common x86-64 platform, whereas Octave uses floating point. So in Julia mh(500,50) overflows. You can fix it by replacing mh() as follows:

```
function mh(n, dvc)
    n2 = BigInt(n) # Or n2 = Float64(n)
    if n <= dvc 
        2^n2 #A
    else 
        n2^dvc #B
    end
end
```